# How to assign Mandatory Properties in class object in C#

Tags: c#, oop, c#-2.0

Im working on .Net using c#. In c# classes want to use optional properties, like i have PERSON class, in that have properties like NAME,AGE,CITY and GENDER.

```
 public class PERSON
 {
   public string NAME{get; set;};
   public int AGE {get; set;}
   public string CITY {get; set;}
   public string GENDER {get; set;}
 }
```

now i assigned the property values for NAME,AGE AND CITY.

```
 PERSON objper = new PERSON();
 objper.NAME="ABC";
 objper.AGE="22";
 objper.CITY="NYC";

 string strresult = calPerson(objper);
```

now im passing this PERSON object 'objper' to one method, which returns the property values of PERSON in xml format like below.Im not passing the value for GENDER property.

```
 public string calPerson(PERSON objPerson)
{
   //"<xml><name>abc</name><age>22</age><city>nyc</city><gender></gender></xml>"
   return xml formated string.
}
```

while creating xml formatted string im getting GENDER node with null value even though not sending any value to it.

i want only

```
    <xml>
       <name>abc</name><age>22</age><city>nyc</city>
    </xml>
```

as output.

Now i have another method calGender() which accepts PERSON object.

```
 objper = new PERSON();
 objper.GENDER="male";

public string calGender(PERSON objPerson)
{
   //"<xml><name></name><age></age><city></city><gender>male</gender></xml>"
   return xml formated string.
}
```

while creating xml formatted string im getting name,age and city nodes value with null even though not sending any value to it.

i want only

```
       <xml>
          <gender>male</gender>
       </xml>
```

as output.

so, 
i want to use NAME,AGE AND CITY properties to calPerson() method only. I do not want GENDER property in the PERSON class.
i want to use GENDER property to calGender() method only.i do not want NAME,AGE and CITY properties in PERSON class.

Please suggest me how to do this...

AnilJayanti.

Answer (score 2):

You can very well use the built in serializer like `DataContractSerializer` or the `XmlSerializer` and use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to skip any properties that you do not want to serialize.

For more details, refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the built in XML serialiser? If so, try creating some additional `PERSON` properties with the same names, but adding the suffix `Specified`, for example:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool GENDERSpecified { get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(GENDER); } }
```

This should instruct the XMLSerialiser to only output the GENDER node if it has a value.

Full details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class PERSON
 {
   public string NAME{get; set;}
   public int AGE {get; set;}
   public string CITY {get; set;}

 }
class PERSON1 : PERSON
{
      public string GENDER {get; set;}
}
```

Use PERSON in calling "calPerson()' and PERSON1 in "calGender()"